# Similar values in range make it as a KEY and sum function

Tags: vba, excel

Cheers, everyone! It is a bit complicated to me to express the code below, but i will give it a shot. The code bellow is supposed to do the following things:

1.Check the range from columns **D, E, H** and **M**. Columns **D, E** and **H** have similar values in their range i.e.: **D5 = V** and **D6 = V** ; **E5 = B** and **E6 = B** ; **H5 = A** and **H6 = A**, while column **M** has digits as values i.e. **M5 = 40** and **M6 =70**.

2.Column M (meaning Range(m5:m50) must sum up the values from M5 and M6: 40 + 70. The reason why it sums up is because range(**D5:D6, E5:E6, H5:H6**) have similar values in their columns. Only then the sumfunction must kick in **range("m5:m50")**, when all the other columns mentioned (**D, E and H**) have similar values in their range. Take it as key (**D5&E5&H5 = VBA ; D6&E6&H6 = VBA**). Both are similar. Then, If

3.Those 2 values from range("m5:m50") is  **> 100**,  both cells (**M5** and **M6** turn red). Otherwise, no action is taken.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim cell As Range

            Application.EnableEvents = False

        For Each cell In Target

                            If (cell.Range("d5:d50").Value) & (cell.Range("e5:e50").Value) & (cell.Range("h5:h50").Value) Then
                                Sum1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(cell.Range("m5:m50"))

                                If Sum1 > 100 Then

                                   cell.Range("m5:m50").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

                    Else
                                   cell.Range("m5:m50").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

                            End If
                            End If
                   Next

            Application.EnableEvents = True

        End Sub
```

My code doesn't seem to work, but I do not get also any error. I would really appreciate if someone can help me to fix my problem as I am out of ideas. Thanks in advance!

Comment: not quite sure about your question but try closing your file and open again as Application.EnableEvents = false and Application.EnableEvents = True might affect it. hope it helps :)

Comment: Your first `If` doesn't check for anything. Also, what are you passing as Target? Start by adding `Option Explicit` at the top of your module and declaring all your variables, it will help you organise your code.

Comment: Are you expecting `Target` to be referencing a `Sheet` or a `Range`? I ask as you appear to be trying to use it as a `Sheet` when the `Worksheet_Change` event returns the range of cells that have changed. So if cell C5 is changed, you're then asking it to look at d5:d5 ***from*** C5, which I don't think you want.

Comment: @dadler , yes, I get an error on my first IF now., but I don't know how else should I write the condition..

Comment: @CLR yes, as a range. I want my range from  column M to look at column D, E and H only when those column have similar values..

Comment: Are they suppose to be similar or equal values? If they are similar, what are they? Strings ? Values withing a range of values? You say "values like" but your examples use "=". Can you try to clarify your needs?

Comment: @dadler, they are suppose to be similar, so column D, E, H should be strings, while M must be integer. Thanks

Comment: How similar? Is a string "1,00000" similar enough to the integer 1? If they don't have to be strictly identical, then you have to layout rules to define what you consider similar or not. To add to this: should we be converting the strings to integers and then comparing them to the integers in column M ?

Comment: @dadler i think this is becoming to confusing for the knowledge I have in VBA. I just don't understand why i should define rules that needs to consider if they are similar or not. As long as the column is defined as an integer/string shouldn't that be enough? If i.e. Column D, E, H and M are defined as Integer and row5 and row6 have similar data in columns D =V, E =B and H= A, the If condition should then sum up the digits from column M(row5 + row6). That is the solution I could come up. If something must broad must be defined, then I do not know how to proceed with that.. Thanks

Comment: The reason I ask is because in VBA you have the [Like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator) operator.

Comment: I think you're either misunderstanding the way the Event `Target` is to be used, or you misunderstand how to reference a cell. For example, you check `cell.Range("d5:d50").Value`, but `cell` is variable, i.e. is based on *which cell has just been changed*. So if you change cell `A5` for instance, `cell.Range("d5:d50").Value` will try to return the `.Value` of of cell `D9:D54` - i.e. `A5` offset by `D5:D50`

Comment: @dadler I see now. No, the operator "like" must not be defined.

Comment: @CLR the reason why I defined **cell** was in order to turn all the cells from column M to red if their sum value is higher than 100. I don't know how to come up with another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if my understanding is correct, I propose this adaptation to your code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum1 As Long, k As Long, c(50) As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 5 To 49
        sum1 = 0
        k = 0
        For j = i + 1 To 50
            If Cells(i, 4) = Cells(j, 4) And Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5) And Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 8) Then
                If sum1 = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 13): k = 1: c(k) = i: Cells(i, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                sum1 = sum1 + Cells(j, 13)
                k = k + 1
                c(k) = j
                Cells(j, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            End If
        Next j
        If sum1 > 100 Then
            For j = 1 To k
                Cells(c(j), 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

A more robust version of the code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum1 As Long, k As Long, c(50) As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("M5:M50").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For i = 5 To 49
        k = 0
        For j = i + 1 To 50
            If Cells.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                If Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
                    If Cells(i, 4) = Cells(j, 4) And Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5) And Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 8) Then
                        If k = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 13): k = 1: c(k) = i
                        sum1 = sum1 + Cells(j, 13)
                        k = k + 1
                        c(k) = j
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        If sum1 > 100 Then
            For j = 1 To k
                Cells(c(j), 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code. I am getting the following error when using it: **Run-time Error '9':Subscript out of range**. Should be because of my Excel worksheet? Thanks

Comment: did you change the number of rows from 50 to a higher value ?

Comment: No, I haven't change anything. I have to be honest and say that I just copied your code and pasted it, as I wouldn't have been able to write it. The error goes to **: c(k) = i:** as seems that this is **row51** - goes out of range. Thanks

Comment: replace this instruction If sum1 = 0 Then `sum1 = Cells(i, 13): k = k + 1: c(k) = i: Cells(i, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)` by this one `If sum1 = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 13): k = 1: c(k) = i: Cells(i, 13).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)`

Comment: yes, it works now. The only problem is that it turns only cell M5 in red, not also M6. Both must be red if the total value of both is higher than 100. Still, I really appreciate your effort. I wouldn't have been able to do something like this. Thanks

Comment: I made a test file based on your input, M5 and M6 are both red when this macro is run.

Comment: I try to play with your code, and I would like to ask you a question if I am not asking that much. I tried to change in the code **> 100** to **< 100**. What happened next when the 2 values were < 100 i.e. M5 = 40 and M6 = 50, was to color all the cells from range("m5:m50") to red. Would you be kind to explain me why is it so? I mean, why not only cells m5 and m6 turned red? Is it something else that needs to be replaced in the code? Thanks

Comment: Again I cannot reproduce the problem with my test file. However, I made another version of the code.

Comment: I hope I am not asking for too much again. I am using your last code provided as it is doing the job I needed. However, I tried to use the code for other cases as well, and the only thing I have changed on it was to change the sign **> 100** to **<> 100**. So if the sum of the cell is less or higher than 100, then the cells turn red. The problem is that when the sum = to 100, the only cell that turns **white** is the first cell of the entry. The other ones still remain **red**. Can you please help me fix this? I am in really need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 18 Jan 2018

    Const FirstRow As Long = 5                  ' adjust as required
    Const LastRow As Long = 50                  ' adjust as required

    Dim Rng As Range                            ' M5:M50
    Dim Test1 As String                         ' concatenate values D:H
    Dim Test2 As Boolean                        ' Sum(M5:M50) > 100
    Dim Arr As Variant
    Dim R As Long

    With Target
        ' columns D, E, H, M
        If IsError(Application.Match(.Column, Array(4, 5, 8, 13), 0)) Then Exit Sub
        If .Row < FirstRow Or .Row > LastRow Then Exit Sub
    End With

    Arr = Range(Cells(FirstRow, "D"), Cells(LastRow, "H")).Value
    R = LBound(Arr)
    Test1 = Arr(R, 1) & Arr(R, 2) & Arr(R, 5)    ' columns D, E and H

    For R = (R + 1) To UBound(Arr)
        If StrComp(Test1, (Arr(R, 1) & Arr(R, 2) & Arr(R, 5)), vbTextCompare) Then Exit For
    Next R

    If R > UBound(Arr) Then
        Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, "M"), Cells(LastRow, "M"))
        Test2 = (Application.Sum(Rng) > 100)
    End If

    ' Setting range to colour red: adjust as required
    Set Rng = Range(Cells(FirstRow, "M"), Cells(FirstRow + 1, "M"))
    Rng.Interior.Color = IIf(Test2, 255, xlNone)
End Sub
```

I found your code at apparent variance with your task description with regard to which cells to colour red. My code follows your description (or how I understood it) and only colours M5:M6. However, I think you will be able to tweak this detail of the code easily enough, or any other part of it, once you learn how it works. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for taking out of your time. I tried to implement your code as well, but I couldn't make it work. Didn't receive any error while running it so I don't know exactly where the problem is. To be honest, I just copied your code and run it. Still, your explanations make it easy to understand the steps, just cannot figure it out why it didn't work. The solution provided by **h2so4** did the job I needed. Again, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be writing your own conditional formatting. I've no idea why you're doing this, instead of using conditional formatting but if you insist on reinventing the wheel.. I believe the following will do what you want.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim thisrowtext As String, nextrowtext As String

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell In Me.Range("m5:m50")

        thisrowtext = cell.Offset(0, -9).Text & cell.Offset(0, -8).Text & cell.Offset(0, -5).Text
        nextrowtext = cell.Offset(1, -9).Text & cell.Offset(1, -8).Text & cell.Offset(1, -5).Text

        If thisrowtext = nextrowtext And cell.Value > 100 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Else
                cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        End If
    Next

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking out of your time. I didn't try to reinvent the wheel. Was just the way I could come up with a solution, or to put it in another way, this is the knowledge I have in VBA. Again, many thanks!

Comment: I just understood properly your comment now. So you say that all this code can be avoided and write instead an Excel formula in conditional formatting that can take all those assumptions into consideration? thanks

Comment: Hi Alex, maybe. Based on ***my*** understanding of your requirements, yes, but now I've read your accepted answer, I'm wondering if perhaps I've misunderstood them myself.