# Unable to get the interior property of the range class - Run time error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is taken from the link [Similar values in range make it as a KEY and sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48317371/similar-values-in-range-make-it-as-a-key-and-sum-function/48319062?noredirect=1#comment83632413_48319062), however, I have made small adjustments to it (adding more cells to be checked). What the code does, is to check if columns 4, 5, 8, 36 and 37 have similar values/text in their cells. If yes, then it looks in column 59 and uses the sum function to check if the values of the similar entries are **less** or **higher** than **100**. If yes, then the cells in **column 59** turn **red**, if not, they should remain **white**.

Example:

- Column 4: Cell D5, D6 and D7 - all are P11
- Column 5: Cell E5, E6 and E7 - all are P12
- Column 8: Cell H5, H6 and H7 - all are P13
- Column 36: Cell AJ5, AJ6 and AJ7 - all are P14
- Column 37: Cell AK5, AK6 and AK7 - all are P15
- Column 59: Cell BG5 = 40 and BG6 = 20 and BG7 = 30. Total value: 90 which does not equal 100. Henceforth, BG5, BG6 and BG7 must turn red. (the sum function works only when the other columns mentioned have similar value in their rows)

The code worked when it was checking only the columns 4, 5 and 8 and no error was received. However, after I added also the columns 36 and 37, the following error is received: **Unable to get the interior property of the range class - Run time error 1004** and I don't know how to solve this.

**Note**: The columns 4, 5, 8, 36, 37 and 59 also have the conditional formatting formula **isblank** to turn the cells red if they are empty. The reason for that is because people need to know that those cells are mandatory to complete.

Thanks for your help and time!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum1 As Long, k As Long, c(5000) As Long
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("bg5:bg5000").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For i = 5 To 4999
        k = 0
        For j = i + 1 To 5000
           If Cells.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                If Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 8) & Cells(i, 36) & Cells(i, 37) <> "" Then
                    If Cells(i, 4) = Cells(j, 4) And Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5) And Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 8) And Cells(i, 36) = Cells(j, 36) And Cells(i, 37) = Cells(j, 37) Then
                        If k = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 59): k = 1: c(k) = i
                        sum1 = sum1 + Cells(j, 59)
                        k = k + 1
                        c(k) = j
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        If sum1 <> 100 Then
            For j = 1 To k
                Cells(c(j), 59).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't know if this would cause your error, but do you have any error values in any cells? Which line actually errors? Have you checked the values of variables when it errors?

Comment: the syntax of this instruction is not correct `If Cells.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then`

Comment: do you actually want to run this everytime you type a value into any cell on the worksheet?

Comment: I don't have any error values in any cells. The line that gets the error is: `If Cells.Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then `. Thanks

Comment: @h2so4 - I also wondered about `If Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 8) & Cells(i, 36) & Cells(i, 37) <> "" Then`.

Comment: I think as @h2so4 says that line is wrong, but it will always have been wrong, it can't suddenly have caused a problem because you added new columns.

Comment: @SJR - `If Cells(i, 4) ...` actually turns out to be a really clever way to check whether all these cells are empty.

Comment: No, I want to run this only when I insert numbers  in column 59.

Comment: @Vityata - I suspected as much but wasn't sure without checking. It suggests the <> "" is redundant though.

Comment: @SJR - not exactly redundant. Imagine that on `Cells(i, 4)` you had `False` written as a value. Then w/o the `<>""` you would have `False` and with it you would have `True`.

Comment: @Vityata - are you saying that `If Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5)<> ""` is equivalent to `If Cells(i, 4)<>"" & Cells(i, 5)<> ""`?

Comment: Pretty much, if you change the `&` sign to `AND` on the 2 example, then the result would be the same (the actions are not the same). The idea of the `Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) <> ""` is that it concatenates the values to a string and it then does the comparison with `""`.

Comment: @Vityata - ok I'm with you, a bit slow off the mark this morning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here a proposal to adapt the code. Note that the macro runs each time you enter a value in column 59 and that it executes the code insides the loop for about 2500000 times, this may take some time.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum1 As Long, k As Long, c(5000) As Long
    If Target.Column <> 59 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("bg5:bg5000").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For i = 5 To 4999
        k = 0
        If Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 8) & Cells(i, 36) & Cells(i, 37) <> "" Then
            If Cells(i, 59).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                For j = i + 1 To 5000
                    If Cells(j, 59).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
                        If Cells(j, 4) & Cells(j, 5) & Cells(j, 8) & Cells(j, 36) & Cells(j, 37) <> "" Then
                            If Cells(i, 4) = Cells(j, 4) And Cells(i, 5) = Cells(j, 5) And Cells(i, 8) = Cells(j, 8) And Cells(i, 36) = Cells(j, 36) And Cells(i, 37) = Cells(j, 37) Then
                                If k = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 59): k = 1: c(k) = i
                                sum1 = sum1 + Cells(j, 59)
                                k = k + 1
                                c(k) = j
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
                If sum1 <> 100 Then
                    For j = 1 To k
                        Cells(c(j), 59).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Next j
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

code adapted, if you want to link it to a button, add a button, right-click on the button and assign this macro (aargh) to it.

```
Sub aargh()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, sum1 As Long, k As Long, c(5000) As Long, fl(5000) As Boolean
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    Range("bg5:bg5000").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    For i = 5 To 4999
        k = 0
        s1 = Cells(i, 4) & Cells(i, 5) & Cells(i, 8) & Cells(i, 36) & Cells(i, 37)
        If s1 <> "" Then
            If Not fl(i) Then
                For j = i + 1 To 5000
                    If Not fl(j) Then
                        s2 = Cells(j, 4) & Cells(j, 5) & Cells(j, 8) & Cells(j, 36) & Cells(j, 37)
                        If s2 <> "" Then
                            If s1 = s2 Then
                                If k = 0 Then sum1 = Cells(i, 59): k = 1: c(k) = i: fl(i) = True
                                sum1 = sum1 + Cells(j, 59)
                                k = k + 1
                                c(k) = j
                                fl(j) = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next j
                If sum1 <> 100 Then
                    For j = 1 To k
                        Cells(c(j), 59).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    Next j
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks again for your help. Is it possible then to have this code under a button so I can avoid slowing down the sheet every time I insert a digit? I know that I have to change `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` to `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()`, but then it won't work. Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, I have checked the code, and if the values equal 100, the only cell that turns red is the 1st cell, in my example, BG5. The other ones, still remained red.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the <>100 test. This algorithm doesn't work for this kind of test.

Comment: Thanks. This works now even though I have the <>. The code does its job. Many thanks for that!